# Debugger: Search for a variable which is used

Tags: debugging, abap

I have the following problem:

I want to avoid that one field of the copied row gets copied into the new row. (ME51n)
I thought that I could search somewhere in the debugger for this field name.

Example:

first row has the `MATNR`: 100-1-15

now i want to search in the debugger for the field `MATNR`. Is this possible?
(I know this example does not make sense, but my field is not used that often because it's an self-created field)

Or is there an user-exit especially for that?

Comment: Did You use watchdogs ? You can also set up breakpoints conditionally.
Would this help You ?

Comment: I know that I can use breakpoints conditionally. But I don't know, which condition I should use.

Comment: and watchdogs ?

Observe a variable, when it changes to "space" or whatever then the program also stops.

Comment: I just know my field. And that field will copied into another field, which I dont know. So i can't find the right variable.

Comment: I'm lookong for an user-exit by the edit event,, where i can decide, which field Iwant to copy and which not.

Comment: I meant I search an user-exit by the copy-event

Comment: Ahh, then i would debug. You have no other choice, afaik.

Comment: And how do I know, that an user-exit is called?

Comment: Each module has specific sets of exits, via exit or badi. Inspect them first look if any is flsgged as active. Go into suspicious modules/methods, inspect them or set a bp.

Answer (score 0):

Use watchpoints for that particular aim that you stated. In [official documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/49/26d98dc93016b8e10000000a42189d/content.htm?frameset=/en/49/2064f3d0fc14cfe10000000a42189b/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/64/d255cb986147f3a7bad0a000d88174/plain.htm&node_id=288) you can learn how to do it. The problem of finding suitable user-exit is not related to original question.